# how to implement the two Radio Buttons in UITableView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, radio-button

in my project i have a `UITableView`. In that i want to implement two radio buttons.in my project i want to choose a gender for three employee Details. below image is explaining my questions.

[image]

in this i want to select a gender for each row but it not selecting

help me

Comment: Use `UISegmentedControl`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of third party libraries with which you can achieve this. like [this](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGViews) and [this](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton).

You can find more in [CocoaControls.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=radio)